# Visual Studio 2022 does not show work items when typing "#nnn" in Git Changes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In VS2019, when I typed in the Git Changes message box, if I typed a #, followed by a number, it would show me matching work items, and allow me to choose one. That work item would then be associated with the commit.

VS2022 doesn't do this. Typing # is just like typing any other character.

Is there a way to get back the VS2019 behavior?

---

Just found out that one of my colleagues has the old behavior. As far as I know, neither of us have changed any settings for this, but he gets the work items offered and I don't.

Comment: VS can operate git w/o being logged into the remote Git portal, but needs to be logged in at the azure git portal to do the associations. Verify that the `Git Changes` screen is connected to the remote hosted Azure Devops portal with the credentials which would be authenticated to get the work items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somtimes at the Git Changes Portal in both versions the error is:

> This repository's origin remote is hosted in Azure DevOps.  Connect
> to Azure DevOps to enable access to work items and builds.

Make sure you are logged in, and with the proper credentials (email for Azure Devops and not the VS licensing) which are allowed to get the values.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but I'm not clear. I'm not getting an error, I just don't get the work items offered. As far as I know, VS is connected to Azure DevOps (with the DevOps creds, not the VS ones), but how do I check? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, just noticed that if I go to Team Explorer (something I don't use, as I use the Git Changes window), I see a message saying I am not authorised to access dev.azure.com/myusername. I used the Connections button to connect to the project, and now I can see my work items. Thanks very much

Comment: It seemed like in some fashion, you were no longer connected to *the mothership*.

Comment: Yeah, but after I'd had a close encounter of the DevOps kind, all was well :)

Answer (score 0):

It works,
try to reconnect to the git repository